# Cleaning an oddly structured dataframe from an excel file (any recommendations on functions also appreciated)

Tags: r, dataframe, function, grepl

I'm trying to make a dataframe pulled from an excel file more user-friendly by creating a "Type" column.
The data can be found here: https://www.dmo.gov.uk/data/pdfdatareport?reportCode=D1A (direct download excel link here: https://www.dmo.gov.uk/umbraco/surface/DataExport/GetDataExport?reportCode=D1A&exportFormatValue=xls&parameters=%26COBDate%3D11%2F04%2F2011)

As you can probably see, the type of data is all grouped together in column A, like so: [image]

What I'd like to do is is change title "Conventional Gilts" to being "Name", and create a "Type" column that has the different categories pulled from their grouped title. In the linked file, the "Types" would be: "Ultra-Short", "Short", "Medium", "Long", "Index-linked Gilts (3-month Indexation Lag)", "Undated Gilts (non "rump")", and ""Rump" Gilts".

While I feel I would need to do some form of pattern recognition using a package like grepl, I'm not sure how I can achieve this from a 'dynamic' perspective (changing if new categories are created).

Any advice on how to achieve this (or even achieve this in a function) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about a single function to do all this; the data is haphazardly arranged and needs to be fixed "manually", for example:

```r
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

gilts <- read_xls("C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/gilts.xls")

gilts %>% 
  filter(!apply(gilts, 1, function(x) all(is.na(x)))) %>%
  filter(seq(nrow(.)) < 44) %>%
  select(1:7) %>%
  filter(seq(nrow(.)) != 1) %>%
  setNames(unlist(slice(., 1))) %>%
  filter(seq(nrow(.)) != 1) %>%
  mutate(splitter = cumsum(is.na(`ISIN Code`))) %>%
  group_by(splitter) %>%
  mutate(Type = first(`Conventional Gilts`)) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~.x[-1])) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-1) %>%
  select(c(8, 1:7)) %>%
  rename(Name = `Conventional Gilts`) %>%
  mutate(across(c(4, 5, 7),
                ~ as.Date(as.numeric(.x), origin = "1899-12-30"))) %>%
  mutate(across(contains("million"), as.numeric))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'splitter'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 37 x 8
#>    Type        Name     ISIN ~1 Redempti~2 First Is~3 Divid~4 Current/~5 Total~6
#>    <chr>       <chr>    <chr>   <date>     <date>     <chr>   <date>       <dbl>
#>  1 Ultra-Short 9% Conv~ GB0002~ 2011-07-12 1987-07-12 12 Jan~ 2011-07-01   7312.
#>  2 Ultra-Short 3¼% Tre~ GB00B3~ 2011-12-07 2008-11-14 7 Jun/~ 2011-05-26  15747 
#>  3 Ultra-Short 5% Trea~ GB0030~ 2012-03-07 2001-05-25 7 Mar/~ 2011-08-26  26867.
#>  4 Ultra-Short 5¼% Tre~ GB00B1~ 2012-06-07 2007-03-16 7 Jun/~ 2011-05-26  25612.
#>  5 Ultra-Short 4½% Tre~ GB00B2~ 2013-03-07 2008-03-05 7 Mar/~ 2011-08-26  33787.
#>  6 Ultra-Short 8% Trea~ GB0008~ 2013-09-27 1993-04-01 27 Mar~ 2011-09-16   8378.
#>  7 Ultra-Short 2¼% Tre~ GB00B3~ 2014-03-07 2009-03-20 7 Mar/~ 2011-08-26  29123.
#>  8 Short       5% Trea~ GB0031~ 2014-09-07 2002-07-25 7 Mar/~ 2011-08-26  36579.
#>  9 Short       2¾% Tre~ GB00B4~ 2015-01-22 2009-11-04 22 Jan~ 2011-07-13  28181.
#> 10 Short       4¾% Tre~ GB0033~ 2015-09-07 2003-09-26 7 Mar/~ 2011-08-26  33650.
#> # ... with 27 more rows, and abbreviated variable names 1: `ISIN Code`,
#> #   2: `Redemption Date`, 3: `First Issue Date`, 4: `Dividend Dates`,
#> #   5: `Current/Next \nEx-dividend Date`,
#> #   6: `Total Amount in Issue \n(£ million nominal)`
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Different approach, premised on the fact that all the gilts start with numbers and the types do not. Makes use of `janitor` which has super helpful functions for cleaning up messy imported data like this.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(janitor)

import_gilts <- read_excel("20221031 - Gilts in Issue.xls.xls", skip = 7) 

gilts <- import_gilts %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(1, "^Note|^Page")) %>% 
  rename(Name = `Conventional Gilts`) %>% 
  remove_empty(which = "rows") %>% 
  mutate(Type = case_when(str_detect(Name, "^[^0-9]") ~ Name,
                          TRUE ~ NA_character_),
         .before = Name) %>% 
  fill(Type, .direction = "down") %>% 
  arrange(desc(...9)) %>% 
  row_to_names(row_number = 2) %>% 
  rename(Type = 1,
         Name = 2) %>% 
  filter(Type != Name)
```

Quick draft so there's certainly room for improvement.

Should be able to be turned into a function as long as the number of imported columns and number of rows to skip reading in the file stay the same.